# Powershell: find file name where function is defined

Tags: powershell

Given the function object (i.e. `$f = gi Function:\myfunc`) is it possible to find file name and other info (for instance line number) of the file where function is declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track with `gi`. The ScriptBlock member of the function object has `File` and `StartPosition` among its properties:

```
(gi function:\prompt).ScriptBlock.File
```

Or you can just go with:

```
${Function:myfunc}.File
```